# Add new tag even reputation is low

Tags: discussion, tags

My reputation is not 1500 but i wanted to add some new tags. There are some emerging technologies which should be there in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which tags are missing?

Comment: Can you guess any new technology which is not present on stackoverflow?

Comment: No, I can't. That's why I asked.

Comment: Ok there should be a tag "SDN" "OVS" etc as stack overflow is very good forum and have most of the answers.

Comment: you did vote down for my resonable question :(

Comment: Tags will be added if there are questions which require it.

Comment: SDN = Software-Defined Networking? Sounds more like Serverfault's territory. I can't find anything relevant about OVS, maybe it hasn't "emerged" enough yet. Also, [downvotes work differently on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: googling about "OVS full form" asking me "did you mean EVS full form".. If you think the technology is an emerging one, it would be better if you link to its official site in question.

Comment: Krishnabhadra I edited the question and links are there ONF https://www.opennetworking.org/ is maintaining standards

Comment: Do you actually have a question about these technologies, or have you spotted a question that should have these tags? If not, it's a bit premature to add tags for them (and that's not how tags work: you can't have tags without questions).

Comment: @Juhana There are many related questions

Comment: @SohaibAyub If you give a link to a couple of them, I can go add the tags.

Answer (score 14):

I think you would have better luck if you compiled a list of existing questions you think the tag would apply to. Post it here on Meta along with a description of what the tag means. Then someone with enough rep could create it for you if they agreed that it was a good idea.

The fact that you don't have a high enough rep to do it yourself doesn't mean it can't be done. It just means you need to convince the community that it is a good idea. And without  concrete evidence at least some things would be improved if it were added, you're not going to convince anyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have privileges to create tags, just add a comment on question to create a new tag for the question and explain the reason and also explain something about the new tag. Probably users with this privileges will create the new tag for you if found helpful if not they will reply you via comment. Please wait for a while (may be a day!), if no one reply you, flag a question for moderator's attention, choose *other* and explain there the reason. Moderator's action will be the final. If they decline your flag that means there is no need for that tag.

Comment: There are some tags and i have some references also:
SDN: Software Defined Networking
OVS: Open Vswitch etc.. Many other i can tell..
Some of the References
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_networking
http://openvswitch.org/
https://www.opennetworking.org/